# Rotate Image on Slide Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm currently trying to rotate an image on this site http://theflouringartisans.com/ The goal is to have the arrow images at the top rotate when the contact form is expanded and rotate again when the form is collapsed. This is the code I currently have:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#contactbutton").click(function(){
                if ($("#contact").is(":hidden")){
                    $("#contact").slideDown("slow");
                    $(".arrow").rotateRight(180);
                }
                else{
                    $("#contact").slideUp("slow");
                    $(".arrow").rotateRight(180);
                }
            });

        });

        function closeForm(){
            $("#thankyou").show("slow");
            setTimeout('$("#thankyou").hide();$("#contact").slideDown("slow")', 2000);
       }
```

I would also like to have the div #thankyou to fade out after 5 seconds from the form being submitted.

Any help is greatly appreciated and I thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never heard jQuery function called rotateRight(), but you can do this with [css3 rotate](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp) and some jQuery mix.

[here is css3 rotating animation example, mouse over the green box here.](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#contactbutton").click(function(){
          if ($("#contact").is(":hidden")){
                 $("#contact").slideDown("slow");
                 $(".arrow").addClass('rotateRight');
          }else{
                 $("#contact").slideUp("slow");
                 $(".arrow").removeClass('rotateRight');
          }
      });
});
```

css:

```
.rotateRight {
transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Firefox */

/* if you want to do this move with animate use transition */
transition: .5s;
-moz-transition: .5s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: .5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: .5s; /* Opera */

}
```